# How can a child process inherit data from parent process using fork()?

Tags: c++, arrays, fork, parent-child

I'm creating a child process using fork(). Since child process inherits data from the parent process, I'm creating an array in the parent process and calling a calc function inside my child process, which calculates the sum of all elements with odd index inside the array. It gives me an error...

```
Conrados-MBP:oshw3 conrados$ make
g++ -c -Werror main.cc
main.cc:33:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'arr'
                int sum = calc(arr);
```

If child process inherits data, in this case, the array 'arr' inside the parent class, why then is it giving me this error? My code is below.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/*
calculate the production of all elements with odd index inside the array
*/ 
int calc(int arr[10]) {
    int i=0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i=1; i<10; i=i+2) {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }

    return sum;
} // end of calc


int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    /* fork a child process */
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) { /* error occurred */
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
        printf("I am the child process\n");
        // the child process will calculate the production 
        // of all elements with odd index inside the array
        int sum = calc(arr);
        printf("sum is %d\n", sum);
        _exit(0);
    }
    else { /* parent process */
        /* parent will wait for the child to complete */
        printf("I am the parent, waiting for the child to end\n");
        // the parent process will create an array with at least 10 element
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 23, 45 };
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
} // end of main
```

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ; in your program above, use `exit`(not `_exit`) otherwise stdout won't be properly flushed. Explaining `fork` may need an entire book (or several chapters in it).

Comment: `fork` doesn't magically change the scoping rules of C++.

Comment: Perhaps moving `int arr[] = ...` above `pid_t pid;` might help?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - I get a blank page at the link?

Comment: Also why are you using a C++ compilers to compile C code?

Comment: it was a freely downloadable book, here is a copy http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/%7Ehungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf

Comment: Read also http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/

Answer (score 2):

As far as the compiler is concerned, `fork` is just a normal function.

```
    int sum = calc(arr);
```

At this point in the code, there is no `arr` variable in scope, so you get an error.

Looking at it the other way, `fork` creates a copy of the running process. At the point of `fork`, there is no `arr` array in the parent process, so the child process won't have it either. `arr` is only created later on, after the `fork`:

```
    // the parent process will create an array with at least 10 element
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 23, 45 };
```

If you want the variable to exist in both processes, you need to create it before you call `fork`.

Comment: Each process has its own virtual address space. So the variable is not the "same" in  both.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yeah, I said it's a copy of the running process.